# CSS [attribute=value] selector does not get applied

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have a `div`. I want it to change color between red and green when clicked.

I wrote two working functions in JS to accomplish this.
One called `works` just changes the color.
One called `doesntWork` negates attribute `clicked`, and depends on CSS to change the color, which doesn't happen. **Why? And how can I fix this?**

```js
function doesntWork(div) {
    div.clicked = !div.clicked
    console.log(div.clicked)    
}

function works(div) {
    // console.log(div.style['background-color'])
    if(div.style['background-color'] === "red"){
      div.style['background-color'] = "green"
    }
    else {
      div.style['background-color'] = "red"
    }             
}
```

```css
div {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
div[clicked="true"] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="works(this)"></div>
<div onclick="doesntWork(this)"></div>
```

Comment: `clicked` is not an attribute anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re not setting an *attribute* `clicked` but a *property*. The code below demonstrates how to use `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` correctly. Also, for custom properties you should use the `data-` prefix.

You need to use the ternary condition, instead of simply negating it: on the first click, the attribute is `null`. Negating it yields `true`, which is then set as an attribute and converted to a string `'true'`. Negating this a second time will make it `false` → `'false'`. Not because it was `'true'`, but because it was a *non-empty string*! Any further click will keep the attribute value at `'false'`.

Also, because the attribute is neither `'true'` nor `'false'` at the first time, this is checking whether it’s *not* `'true'`.

```js
function doesntWork(div) {
    div.setAttribute('data-clicked',div.getAttribute('data-clicked')!='true'?'true':'false');
    console.log(div.getAttribute('data-clicked'));
}

function works(div) {
    // console.log(div.style['background-color'])
    if(div.style['background-color'] === "red"){
      div.style['background-color'] = "green";
    }
    else {
      div.style['background-color'] = "red";
    }             
}
```

```css
div {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
div[data-clicked="true"] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="works(this)"></div>
<div onclick="doesntWork(this)"></div>
```

Comment: Why `div.getAttribute('data-clicked')!='true'?'true':'false'` instead of just `!div.getAttribute('data-clicked')`

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus `!div.getAttribute('clicked')` will just set it to `'false'` everytime (except the first time), because a negated non-empty string is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

This function don't work, because there aren't `clicked` attribute in `div` [specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-DIV). This type of selector you can use just for attributes, you can't create your own.

Comment: the "onclick" is just an javascript event you fire... you could set/reset a class to the div to use a css selector on it.